# SetInterval not refreshing HTML in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, timer, safari, setinterval

I'm trying to implement a script that essentially counts down from 30 seconds to 0, and at 0, redirects to the homepage. However, I noticed that my script only works on Firefox but not Chrome and Safari. On these browsers, the counter remains "stuck" at 30 seconds—never refreshing the HTML, but the redirect works fine. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if setInterval is not the right method for this kind of thing.

```
<script>
   var seconds = 31;
   var counter = setInterval("timer()", 1000);
   function timer() {
        seconds = seconds - 1;
        if (seconds < 0) {
            setTimeout("location.href='http://www.homepage.com';", 100);
            return;
        }
        updateTimer();
   }

   function updateTimer() {
         document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = "Redirecting in " + " " + seconds + " " +  "seconds";
   }
  </script>
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: So weirdly enough, my code (and all of yours) is working on JSFiddle, but it's just failing to "repaint" the HTMLinner when it's actually rendering the page. The seconds are changing fine (I outputted them to the console), the changes just aren't rendering.

Final Edit: This problem basically resulted from invalid CSS. I believe—the counter was running above the photo and I set the span to relative positioning with a higher z-index and top and bottom elements. I don't believe this is acceptable for something that is not a block.

Comment: The code runs for me. Any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors on the console—it just doesn't work correctly, which is a little strange I think. I'm wondering if it has to do with browser delay.

Comment: call the function onload or document ready instead of the initial timer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a working sample:

```js
(function() { // wrapper for locals
  var timer = document.getElementById("timer"),
    seconds = 5,
    counter = setInterval(function() {
      if (--seconds < 1) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        timer.innerHTML = "Redirecting now...";
        setTimeout(function() {
          location.href = 'http://www.homepage.com';
        }, 500);
      } else {
        timer.innerHTML = timer.innerHTML.replace(/\d+/, seconds);
      }
    }, 1000);
})();
```

```html
<div id="timer">Redirecting in 5 seconds</div>
```

​
    ​

Comment: Just be careful that you aren't overriding an existing function on window.onload

Comment: Thanks! So, weirdly enough, this isn't working on the actual rendered page, which is admittedly a bizarre turn. I noticed the second incrementation is perfectly timed, but the innerHTML just isn't rendering the changes. Any possibilities?

Comment: Just figured out what the issue is, but would love if someone could explain to me why (just for the future! :) ) As a div, it renders it perfectly, but as a span it doesn't. I'm assuming it has something to do with the way blocks work. Apologies for the misdiagnosis!

Comment: So I'll give you a little bit more context; it basically resulted in invalid CSS I believe—the counter was running above the photo and I set the span to relative positioning with a higher z-index and top and bottom elements. I want to say that had something to do with it; I think it was rendering the new counter beneath the photo. (could be wrong) Would it be helpful if I posted the html and css?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner implementation with fewer defined functions (with [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hLJkK/)):

```
<span id='timer'></span>
<script>
var seconds = 31;
setInterval(function() {
  seconds = seconds - 1;
  if (seconds < 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = "redirecting..."}, 100);
    return;
  }
  updateTimer();
}, 1000);

function updateTimer() {
  document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = "Redirecting in " + + seconds + " seconds";
}
<script>
```

Of course every JavaScript programmer should any opportunity to point out that "eval is evil" which includes passing a string to setInterval and setTimeout :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to a variable, that worked for me:

```
<script>
   var seconds = 31;
   var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
   var timer = function() {
        seconds = seconds - 1;
        if (seconds < 0) {
            setTimeout("location.href='http://www.homepage.com';", 100);
            return;
        }
        updateTimer();
   }

   function updateTimer() {
         document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = "Redirecting in " + " " + seconds + " " +  "seconds";
   }
  </script>
```